# HTML mail class name changes

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to mail a html type email and its working, but the problem is when I send a div with class name, when it arrives, the class name changes.

So what I write in the php file is:

```
<div class="telo" style="width:60%;margin:0 auto">...
```

And what I can read from the arrived mail is:

```
<div class="m_-4831917718643650012telo" style="width:60%;margin:0 auto">...
```

In every div.
So how can I solve this?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Using any third party programs or the pure PHP mail function?

Comment: No third party program used.

Comment: Are you reading the email using a web-based mail reader?

Comment: Many mail readers remove `<style>` tags from HTML email. So you should do all your styling with inline styles, not CSS based on classes.

Comment: See https://mailchimp.com/help/css-in-html-email/ and https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/ for best practices related to HTML email and CSS.

Comment: I wanted the style tag because the @media screen thing, only for optimizing for mobile. And yes I was in a web-based mail reader.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore only classes inside the email message. Every client's mail system works in its own way with that and isn't everywhere fully supported. Always use the style tag as a fall back option

**Maybe useful link to see HTML mail support:**

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/

**Information for Media Queries inside HTML Mail:**

https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email

Comment: Well I'm trying to optimize for mobile. If somebody is reading from a phone, I want to change the width to 90%. That's why I want to use class in every div which width is 60% for the '@media screen' thing

Comment: Well, you can't change the way your client's mail provider works. All I know that HTML mail isn't fully supported, and can be a painful job to do.

Maybe you can go around it with data attributes but never tested that one. I also updated my answer with a link for more information about Media Queries inside HTML Mail